# Is there a way to gracefully change the rails secret_key_base?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose we want to change our Rails app's `secret_key_base`. Is there a way to do so that doesn't immediately log out all our users?

When upgrading from Rails 3.2 to 4, with the corresponding change from `secret_token` to `secret_key_base`, rails helped with the migration by updating new users' cookies as they came to the site. Once a good portion of users had visited, you could switch to `secret_key_base` exclusively without logging them out.

Is this sort of functionality available to change the `secret_key_base` generally, say if a developer leaves or something like that? The idea would be to set a new `secret_key_base` that will switch over users' cookies as they come to the site. Once a good proportion have visited, you can make the hard switch and remove the old `secret_key_base`.

I found an [old rails pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18772) that seems to start on this functionality, but they appear to have stopped working on it.

Comment: what is your sessions storage?

Comment: you can create a load balancer with on 2 app servers and direct traffic depending on the country and migrate each country separately

Comment: It's been almost 4 months... Have you solved this problem? If you did, it'd be lovely if you shared your solution!

Comment: If you did not, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35013568/rails-4-how-to-decrypt-rails-4-session-cookie-given-the-session-key-and-secret)

Comment: After spending a weekend writing a gem to do this, I discovered that this will be possible to do in Rails 5.2, not just with secret_key_base, but also other parameters such as [salts, ciphers, and digests](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8b0af54bbe5ab8b598e980013dd53a50d819b636).

Answer (score 1):

In order to make this work you should customize rails itself versioning it. I don't think this answer would be the choosen but I would like to warn you about how deep this changes can be and the lack of security that you'll bring to your app.

Answer (score -4):

**firstly generate secret**

```
rake secret
```

**and set these values in config/secrets.yml**

```
development:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>

test:
  secret_key_base:

production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

**and then set you secret key into your .bashrc**

```
gedit .bashrc
```

**paste it at the end of file**

```
export SECRET_KEY_BASE='YOUR SECRET KEY'
```

Comment: These steps don't address the question being asked.

Answer (score -6):

rails < 5
    `rake secret`

rails 5
    `rails secret`

Comment: This does not address the issue of OP.

Comment: This tasks invalidates old sessions/cookies If not you can try to destroy all old sessions. Create an special route for them. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html

Comment: is this, even an answer??